# perl and bash external command difference

Tags: bash, perl

My `name.txt` has contains:

```
Tom
Daniel
James
```

In Perl,

```
my $names = `cat names.txt`;
print $names;
```

gives me:

```
Tom
Daniel
James
```

In Bash,

```
names=`cat names.txt`
echo $names
```

gives me:

```
Tom Daniel James
```

Here's my output of `od -c name.txt`:

```
0000000    T  o  m  \n   D   a   n   i   e   l  \n   J   a   m   e   s
0000020
```

What is the reason of the difference?

Comment: Please show how you're implementing the `cat` system call in Perl.

Comment: And how you're using `cat` in Bash directly - disappearing linebreaks smell like a quoting issue.

Comment: Also, please edit the output from `od -c name.txt` into your question.

Comment: Unless 100% sure you don't need them, you should use double quotes around variables in bash ALWAYS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both variables receive the same value, but the way you're examining the value in Bash is flawed: use `echo "$names"` - note the double quotes - to see the true value.

Unquoted use of `$names` in Bash makes its value subject to [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting), which means that the whitespace-separated words in the value - `Tom`, `Daniel`, and `James` - are passed as *separate arguments*  to `echo`, and `echo` concatenates those values with spaces on output.